# Way to tell if view is currently displaying on users screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

I've got this animation that I'd like to run but I only want the animation to run when a user has scrolled down and the item that is in the scrollview is now visible on the users screen. Is there a way to check if a view is currently visible on the users screen to then enable this animation to run? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you could do is the following:

First, get the currently visible area of your scroll view. That is going to be the scroll view's `bound` plus the `contentOffset`.

Second, use the `CGRectContainsRect()` function to determine if your view's frame is inside the visible area.

Here is some example code:

```
CGRect visibleRect;
visibleRect.size = myScrollView.bounds.size;
visibleRect.origin = myScrollView.contentOffset;

CGRect containedViewRect = myView.bounds;

if ( CGRectContainsRect( visibleRect, containedViewRect) && !myView.hidden ) 
{
    // The view is visible!
}
```

Hope this helps!